# Double bass position for very high octave

Tags: double-bass

I recently saw a Punch Brothers show and Paul Kowert repeated a short lick an octave higher and higher until the pitch was higher than I ever thought a double/upright bass could go.  He was definitely off the fingerboard, and may have been playing behind the bridge, but I don't quite remember.  At any rate, are there positions after the fingerboard comes to an end and/or behind the bridge?  If so, how might I refer to them?  I unfortunately have no experience with fretless instruments and have pretty much exhausted all the search keywords I can think of.  Currently surfing YouTube in search of high bass notes via pinched strings...

Comment: Can you post the video? Is it possible that he was playing natural harmonics?

Comment: For any definitive answer, we'll need a video or at least a title of the song.

Comment: Anecdote from a cellist (me): once past the fingerboard, it's possible to play non-harmonic notes just by touching the string at the right location. I suspect it's 'cause the frequency is so high that your finger acts as a hard stop.  It is possible to play notes on the wrong side of the bridge as well, tho' they tend to be dang squeaky.

Comment: @Shevliaskovic i wish i had taken a video of it, but i don't have one

Comment: @Tim it wasn't a part of a song they've recorded.  it was in like a breakdown section they did in the middle of a song.  i don't know how different it is to play harmonics on a double bass, i'm only familiar with it on a guitar.  but i'm pretty sure he had both his hands down by the bridge.

Answer (score 4):

**No, there are no formal positions behind the bridge.**

As a double bassist myself, what I believe you are looking for is this: (v)

*The Simandl method* just would describe that positon as **thumb positon** but the *Rabbath method* would describe it as **6th postion**.

It is also possible however that they are using artificial harmonics to create such high notes.
 [image: this]